# ABP Custom Filter - Cannot get CurrentUserId in DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, aspnetboilerplate

I followed the [Add Custom Data Filter Example](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles%5CHow-To%5Cadd-custom-data-filter-ef-core) on the ABP website to create my own Data Filter. My filter needs to use the currently logged in user, so I am trying to use the `IPrincipalAccessor' to get the currently logged in user, like so:

```
protected virtual long? GetCurrentUserIdOrNull()
        {
            var userId = PrincipalAccessor.Principal?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == AbpClaimTypes.UserId);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId?.Value))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return Convert.ToInt32(userId.Value);
        }
```

However, the PrincipalAccess.Principal is always `null`. I also tried using IAbpSession but noticed that the UserId and TenantId is also always `null`.

I noted that `CreateFilterExpression<TEntity>()` only runs once, at startup, which makes sense, and at this point the UserId/Claims/Session items are `null`, but how do I re-create the expression when it is required, ensuring that the UserId is not null at the point where the user is logged in and my custom data filter needs to be applied?

**EDIT:**

Here is my code:

```
// MyDbContext.cs
...
public IPrincipalAccessor PrincipalAccessor { get; set; }

protected virtual bool IsAllowedUsersFilterEnabled => CurrentUnitOfWorkProvider?.Current?.IsFilterEnabled(AccessConsts.AllowedUsersFilter) == true;

protected virtual long? CurrentUserId => GetCurrentUserIdOrNull();

protected override bool ShouldFilterEntity<TEntity>(IMutableEntityType entityType)
{
    if (typeof(IAllowedUsers).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
        return true;

    return base.ShouldFilterEntity<TEntity>(entityType);
}

// called only once
protected override Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> CreateFilterExpression<TEntity>()
{
    var expression = base.CreateFilterExpression<TEntity>();

    if (typeof(IAllowedUsers).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TEntity)))
    {
        if (CurrentUserId != null)
        {
            // never gets here...
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> allowedUsersFilter = e =>
                        ((IAllowedUsers)e).AllowedUsers.Select(au => au.UserId).Contains(CurrentUserId.Value)
                        || (((IAllowedUsers)e).AllowedUsers.Select(au => au.UserId).Contains(CurrentUserId.Value)) == IsAllowedUsersFilterEnabled;

            expression = expression == null ? allowedUsersFilter : CombineExpressions(expression, allowedUsersFilter);
        }
        else // no user logged in, deny all
        {
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> allowedUsersFilter = e => false;
            expression = expression == null ? allowedUsersFilter : CombineExpressions(expression, allowedUsersFilter);
        }
    }

    return expression;
}

protected virtual long? GetCurrentUserIdOrNull()
{
    // only returns null
    var userId = PrincipalAccessor.Principal?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == AbpClaimTypes.UserId);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId?.Value))
    {
        return null;
    }

    return Convert.ToInt32(userId.Value);
}
...

//

// AppConsts.cs
...
public const string AllowedUsersFilter = "AllowedUsersFilter";
...

// MyCoreModule.cs
...
public override void PreInitialize()
{
    ...
    // also tried registering in the EF Module
    Configuration.UnitOfWork.RegisterFilter(AccessConsts.AllowedUserFilter, true);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be found [here](https://support.aspnetzero.com/QA/Questions/9962/Using-%27PrincipalAccessorPrincipal%27-with-a-Filter-in-ZeroDbContext)

As it's not on Stack Overflow, I'll quote it here:

> Do you use it as explained in [https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles\How-To\add-custom-data-filter-ef-core#configure-dbcontext](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles%5CHow-To%5Cadd-custom-data-filter-ef-core#configure-dbcontext) ?
>
> You can also take a look at https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.EntityFrameworkCore/EntityFrameworkCore/AbpDbContext.cs#L78

Comment: Thanks. I have seen this before, but it simply is not 'executed each time when it is needed'.  The bit in `AbpDbContext.GetCurrentTenantIdOrNull()`, specifically the `CurrentUnitOfWorkProvider` does not provide a `UserId`, which is what I need. I also need the `TenantId` for another Data Filter, but it would appear the underlying issue is that the expression is not recreated when needed.

Comment: @pjdupreez did you follow the whole guide? Including the boilerplate? Because it seems you missed a step.

Comment: Yep. Followed the whole thing. Code in `CreateFilterExpression<TEntity>()` gets called on once and only once, never again. I 'default' the expression to return 'false' if currentUserId is null. Breakpoints only hit the `CreateFilterExpression<TEntity>()` on first run. I'll post my code later, but don't think I missed anything, unless there is some code that needs to be added that call `CreateFilterExpression<TEntity>()`. Dont need to create a Claim as I use `AbpClaimTypes.UserId`. The filter gets registered, and DB Context is configured as per the document, for my scenario, of course

Comment: Dont know if this makes a difference, but I am using a custom repository for the entity I am trying to filter